# Javascript Count up/down script to show the time since logged in

Tags: javascript

I've been googling but could not get the correct script.  Maybe someone can point me in the correct direction?

I need to show the time a user has been active on the site since accessing a certain page.  I am busy with a testing site and the user has for example 1 hour to complete a test so I need to show the time the user has been busy on the test.

I've tried this site:  http://javascriptkit.com/script/cut9.shtml but since I don't know javascript I don't know how to set the time to the time the person has accessed the page.

Comment: You need to be careful here. JavaScript is a client side language, and can easily be modified by the client. If the countdown is merely a friendly indicator to the testee as to how long they have left, then this is nothing to worry about. However, if you're trying to restrict users to 1 hour, you **must** implement some server side logic as well.

Comment: Thank you Matt, it is just an indication, the session will expire when the time is up.

Answer (score 0):

The basic code for this would probably be something like this:

```
var pageVisisted = new Date(); // you should probably store this in a database/attach it to the session or AT LEAST in a cookie
```

`setInterval(function() {
    var timeOnSite = new Date() - pageVisisted;

    var secondsTotal = timeOnSite / 1000;
    var hours = Math.floor(secondsTotal / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor(secondsTotal / 60) % 3600;
    var seconds = Math.floor(secondsTotal)  % 60;

    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}, 1000);`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yRsBw/1/

However in a real world application you will want to store the time the user first started the test on the server and send the remaining time back to the client which you can then count down.

Comment: Thank you, will try it now, do I just put that into the <body>?

Comment: scratch that question, thank you I got it working.  For the other newbies like me, I did the following with Patrick's code:

In the <head> section of your page:  <script type="text/javascript" src="counter.js"></script>

Then in the <body> <span id="counter"></span>

Then above code of Patrick you save in counter.js

Comment: Hi Patrick, just another question, if I need to carry the timer over to the next page?  Is that possible?  I should probably add that I already saved the time the test started in a unix time stamp in php as follows:  $now = time(); and then on the following page $_SESSION['now2'] = $now;

Comment: What you should probably do is return the already elapsed time in seconds to the html (from php) ie when you start the test <code>$_SESSION['start'] = time();</code> and on pages of the test <code>echo var offset= time() -  $_SESSION['start'];</code> then use this as a offset to secondsTotal (secondsTotal = timeOnSite / 1000 + offset); Calculating the offset serverside counters different clocks on client and server